# Promise chain/general code convention/style

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

There is some promise convention best practice  which I can use as reference.

I mean something like when you write then you can do it like this

```
step1().then(step2()).then(retur ...step3())    
   .catch(function(err) {
       console.log(err)
  ;});
```

but I think the more **readable** way is like this

```
step1()
   .then(function() {
      return step2();
   }).then(function() {
      return step3()
   }).catch(function(err) {
      log(err);
   });
```

There is some official recommendation how to its better to write it in term of readability etc...

Comment: Whatever you're used to and your team can understand best is the right way to go. There's also a huge difference between `then(step2())` and `then(function() { return step2() })` in terms of execution order.

Comment: @tadman - Yes I know that :) ,This is just for an example...I mean promises in general

Comment: For what it's worth I tend to use the second style here as often as possible, and it's something that adapts well to using streams where you need to chain `pipe()` calls together.

Comment: No - there is no official documentation on which is better - this is opinion based.

Comment: `then(step2())` looks like a bug. Did you mean `then(step2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating intermediate closures is of no benefit if you already have methods ready to hook up. 
Your two examples are also doing entirely different things. Your first example should look like this.

```
step1()
   .then(step2)
   .then(step3)    
   .catch(function(err) {
       console.log(err)
  ;});
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with that. This is also gonna make your stack traces more readable as well.

This is, because, in this example, you have a bunch of intermediate anonymous functions.
As such the stack trace is gonna be containing references to those anonymous functions, while they serve no value.

```
step1()
   .then(function(val) {
      return step2(val);
   }).then(function(val) {
      return step3(val)
   }).catch(function(err) {
      log(err);
   });
```

In order to prevent the anonymous clutter, you would want to name all your anonymous methods like so.

```
step1()
   .then(function _step2(val) {
      return step2(val);
   }).then(function _step3(val) {
      return step3(val)
   }).catch(function(err) {
      log(err);
   });
```

I'm prefixing them with an underscore as they can't have the same name as the actual method we are calling off course.
This is a bunch of duplication and it doesn't make much sense because the _step2 and step2 functions are entirely identical.

Also note that in your preferred example you are not passing the parameters correctly, I have added that logic above as well, which as you can see, further increases the noise.